# How to make custom overlay Text window (similar to Tool Tip )

Tags: python, pyqt

While designing `QListWidget` and `QListTree` item's display I would like to keep the amount of information displayed to a minimum

```
listItem=QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
listItem.setText("Some short info on item")
```

Instead I would like to implement a overlay window that would be displayed above the listItem user is interested in (similar to ToolTip widget).
It would be great if the user would simply position the mouse over the QListWidget item and being able to display floating "Info on Item" overlay window by pressing some keyboard shortcut. Press shortcut - window is displayed. Press a shortcut again to hide it. Any ideas how to implement this?

Here is the idea:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your key-press event to do something like the following:

```
QtGui.QToolTip.showText(QtGui.QCursor.pos(),"Your long format text...",None)
```

and either set a flag to toggle on-off with the same key-press, or for another key-press do:

```
QtGui.QToolTip.hideText()
```